# List of front-end technologies for becoming good at front-end

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, web, coffeescript, frontend

I understand Bootstrap , I understand YUI (a little) and js/jQuery among other things. But what always confuses me , is how to create a website which looks , let's say something like this :-

http://startupgiraffe.com/

In the back-end, you can use anything from Spring MVC to rails to node's express. But I never seem to get around the front-end part of a webapp. I cannot find anything on reddit or something that would explain how to start from beyond jQuery and coffeescript.

This is not something to ask on stackoverflow , but I hope it will be answered .

Answer (score 1):

Agreed, it's not really a stackoverflow type question, but my 1c worth;

Read the HTML source code, examine the divs and javascript etc with Firebug or Chrome's inspector. Practice, try things, learn, practice, test things, read tutorials, go on a course.... whatever works for you.

The startupgiraffe page is heavily reliant on detecting scroll events - easily done with jQuery or Mootools etc.

I hope this helps, it's not meant to be a negative response. I find the best way to learn is to break apart and try to rebuild... start small and work up.

ps. try the site on a mobile device - not good!